# Dynamic creation of fields from varying xml structure in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

One of the columns in my  log table is of type xml, the xml field stores parameters passed to different stored procedures executed in database. So each xml has got a different format and only the root node stays the same. I want to create a table to copy the data values in xml along with other fields in log table(basically expand each row). Any ideas on how to implement this in sql server 2012?

Sample XML

```
<Notes>
  <Parameters>
    <DimCalendarId>20150505</DimCalendarId>
    <RangeCheckStartDate>2015-04-01 00:00:00.000</RangeCheckStartDate>
    <RangeCheckEndDate>2015-06-30 23:59:59.000</RangeCheckEndDate>
    <StartPeriodDate>2015-05-05 00:00:00.000</StartPeriodDate>
    <EndPeriodDate>2015-05-05 23:59:59.000</EndPeriodDate>
    <ActiveRecordDate>2015-05-05 18:00:00.983</ActiveRecordDate> 
    <PeriodTypeId>4</PeriodTypeId>
    <ProcessingSourceId>2</ProcessingSourceId
  </Parameters>
</Notes>
```

Comment: Can you give us a simple example of input and what you hope to get for the output?

Comment: <Notes>
  <Parameters>
    <DimCalendarId>20150505</DimCalendarId>
    <RangeCheckStartDate>2015-04-01 00:00:00.000</RangeCheckStartDate>
    <RangeCheckEndDate>2015-06-30 23:59:59.000</RangeCheckEndDate>
    <StartPeriodDate>2015-05-05 00:00:00.000</StartPeriodDate>
    <EndPeriodDate>2015-05-05 23:59:59.000</EndPeriodDate>
    <ActiveRecordDate>2015-05-05 18:00:00.983</ActiveRecordDate>
    <PeriodTypeId>4</PeriodTypeId>
    <ProcessingSourceId>2</ProcessingSourceId>
  </Parameters>
</Notes>

Comment: This is how one of the xml feed looks like. They are the parameters passed on stored procedures ran. So that keeps on changing. So I'm trying break those values in xml and put them in a table

Comment: What do you want that table to look like? Also, will other rows have XML that is formatted different, or will the XML just have different values?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: I want to have the column names to be the elements in each xml field so that all the elements from different xml fields to come as column names in the new tables and the consecutive values underneath.